# SqLite: значение id из даты создания. Возможно ли?

Tags: php, sqlite3

При создании статьи, нужно, чтобы её id создавался из даты и имел бы такой вид: 20180926203005 (год, месяц, день, часы, минуты, секунды). Возможно ли это?

```
if ($db->exec("CREATE TABLE 'article'
    ('id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT DATE  NOT NULL  UNIQUE, 
    'title' VARCHAR(20), 
    'category' INT(3), 
    'date' VARCHAR(50))"))

$id = date('YmdHis');

if($db->exec("INSERT INTO user VALUES ('$id','Title Article',Category1,'date('YmdHis')')"))
```

Такая конструкция не работает.

Comment: Это плохая идея. Заведите отдельное поле даты, а `id` оставьте в покое.

Comment: А почему плохая?

Comment: Зачем смешивать то, что для этого не предназначено? А если в одну секунду добавят две записи?

Comment: Ну в общем да. Но, однако, при удалении id=2, остальные не смещаются, и в дальнейшем присваивается по порядку, а id=2 уже не будет в базе.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/740358/6275986

Comment: Спасибо, примерно понял, но не могу понять каков в итоге синтаксис.

Comment: Синтаксис чего? Поставили автоинкремент и забыли про него, БД сама его увеличит.

Comment: Ну, чтобы была непрерывность. Там что-то вроде вот этого ALTER TABLE your_table AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 У меня простенькая бд.

Comment: А зачем Вам это вообще? Ну не будет на 22-ом номере поста, что такого? Наоборот - запарится можно с перенаправлениями и неожиданными статьями, которые, вроде бы, сохранены в закладках и всегда должны открывать твоё любимое видео с рыженькими.

Comment: Ну да, всё логично)